# Shutdown a Windows Server 2012 R2 in C#

Tags: c#, windows-server-2012-r2

How do I shutdown a Windows Server 2012 R2 via C# code?
I disabled Shutdown Tracker manually, than I tried the following code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var psi = new ProcessStartInfo("shutdown", "/s /t 0");
            psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
            psi.UseShellExecute = false;
            Process.Start(psi);
        }
```

However this doesn't seem to do anything on the server. It shuts down my win7 laptop though when I try.
**EDIT**
I already tried to run as Administrator. Behaviour is still the same. This is an AWS virtual instance.

Comment: Is your process sufficiently privileged to use that command? IIRC, you need to issue the "shutdown" command from a privileged shell.

Comment: run your applicatin as administator and test again

Comment: So "shutdown /s /t 0" works with command on that VM? You can also try "shutdown /m MACHINENAME /s /t 0" to see if it works.

Comment: Actually I haven't tried auto shutdown on WS 2012. Maybe a /c COMMENT is mandatory?

Comment: Test the command from the command line by itself.  If it returns an error message, that should answer your question.  Starting as far back as Windows Server 2003, any time you shut down the server you were required to manually provide a reason (comment).  I would be very surprised if that were not still the case.